# Binding a key to execute multiple expression maps in vim

Tags: vim

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-b> ':set bg='.(&bg=='dark' ? "light" : "dark")."<cr>"
nnoremap <expr> <C-b> ':!'.(&bg=='dark' ? "dark" : "light")."<cr>"
```

Both work indivisually, but when I set the keybinding to

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-b> ':set bg='.(&bg=='dark' ? "light" : "dark")."<cr>" \| ':!'.(&bg=='dark' ? "dark" : "light")."<cr>"
```

Only the first one gets executed. How do I make the keybind execute both of these commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the `<expr>` modifier you tell Vim that the *whole* right hand side of the mapping is an expression but the `<bar>` in the middle breaks the expression.

This means that your second expression, that conditionally executes an external command, must be fused with the first one in one way or another. There would be a few ways to do it in this specific case but the simplest is to concatenate the two instead of separating them with a `<bar>`:

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-b> ':set bg='.(&bg=='dark' ? "light" : "dark")."<cr>".':!'.(&bg=='dark' ? "dark" : "light")."<cr>"
```

You could also have a single ternary condition.

But that one-liner is getting dangerously long. That's usually where turning your unmaintainable logic into a readable function starts to make sense:

```
function! ToggleBackground()
    let toggles = { "dark": "light", "light": "dark" }
    let &background = toggles[&background]
    call system(toggles[&background])
endfunction
nnoremap <C-b> <Cmd>call ToggleBackground()<CR>
```